# How to remap LMB

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to remap the left mouse button, but I keep getting the error *target label does not exist*.

What is wrong with my code?

```
key := "S"
Hotkey, LButton, %key%
```

Comment: Take a look at this: [Hotkeys](https://ahkde.github.io/v2/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Intro). LButton::s

Comment: Yes, I know how to make a regular hotkey. But I need to use the command `Hotkey` since the key is read from a file.

Comment: Did you try to specifiy a label and send the key from there? This works for me:

Hotkey, LButton, MyLabel
MyLabel:
key := "S"
Send %key%
return

Comment: Yeah it works like that. But that's a rather roundabout way of doing this. The docs state that `label` can also be a hotkey, so I don't understand why the code I posted doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're not referencing a hotkey or a label, but a variable.

Try something like:

```
Hotkey, Lbutton, ^k

^k::

    MsgBox, It Works!

return
```

The same goes for

```
Hotkey, Lbutton, example

example:

    MsgBox, It Works!

return
```

Hope it helps